# How to avoid console window with .pyw file containing os.system call?

Tags: python, windows, console, windows-console, pythonw

If I save my code files as `.pyw`, no console window appears - which is what I want - but if the code includes a call to `os.system`, I still get a pesky console window. I assume it's caused by the call to `os.system`. Is there a way to execute other files from within my `.pyw` script without raising the console window at all?

Comment: Related: [Running a process in pythonw with Popen without a console](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1813872/95735)

Comment: I believe os.system() opens a NEW cmd process. Try os.execl() to REPLACE the new cmd process with your pythonw.exe process.

Comment: I am experiencing this behavior in Python 3.11.1 without the usage of `os.system`.  Must stem from `logging`, `telnetlib`, `tkinter`, `threading`, or `winsound`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try using the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module (`subprocess.Popen`, `subprocess.call` or whatever) with the argument `shell=True` if you want to avoid starting a console window.

Comment: subprocess.check_call makes a good replacement for os.system in this case.

Comment: Be sure to set `subprocess.check_call(args, shell=True)` where `args` is the command string that you would ordinarily type in a console. I'm not sure why `shell=True` is needed when I __don't__ want a console to appear, but that's what occurred in my experiment.

Comment: Indeed; `subprocess.Popen(...)` will open a console window, `subprocess.Popen(..., shell=True)` will not open a console window. My belief is that with `shell=True` it is run in the current process's subsystem---which will be "window" rather than "console" for `pythonw`---rather than being launched entirely separately, where as a console subsystem executable it will open a new console window.

Comment: I've improved the answer to be more accurate and more specific about what needs doing.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan *My belief is (...)* I think it's not what happens. In fact with `shell=True` every subprocess opens its own console but it's hidden. See [`startup`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) parameter, [subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE) flag, [subprocess.STARTUPINFO.wShowWindow](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.STARTUPINFO) attribute and [this](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/70274d53c1dd/Lib/subprocess.py#l867) line of `subprocess.py`.

Comment: `shell=True` is not necessary here. See my answer and question [How do I eliminate Windows consoles from spawned processes in Python (2.7)?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3390762/95735)

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost: you're absolutely right. I had forgotten I had written that or I would have corrected it - I had occasion to come across the real explanation earlier this year. Thanks for offering the correction!

Answer (score 17):

You should use [`subprocess.Popen`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) class passing as `startupinfo` parameter's value instance of [`subprocess.STARTUPINFO`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.STARTUPINFO) class with `dwFlags` attribute holding [`subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#constants) flag and `wShowWindow` attribute holding [`subprocess.SW_HIDE`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#constants) flag. This can be inferred from reading lines [866-868](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/70274d53c1dd/Lib/subprocess.py#l866) of `subprocess.py` source code. It might be necessary to also pass [`subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#constants) flag as a value of [`creationflags`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) parameter as you run under `pythonw.exe` which does not open a console.

When you use `shell=True` it just happens that all of the above is set correctly but that doesn't mean it's a proper solution. I would argue it's not because it adds overhead of running command interpreter and parsing arguments. In addition you should keep in mind that *(...) the use of shell=True is **strongly discouraged** in cases where the command string is constructed from external input* according to documentation of subprocess module.

Comment: The input wasn't from an external source and I couldn't care less about overhead from parsing the shell command, especially if avoiding it involves the over-complicated solution you describe above.

Comment: Using `shell=True` is not the right thing to do here and the (alleged) complexity of the right solution doesn't change this.

Comment: I can't believe this is not the highest voted answer. All because people can't be bothered to write 3 lines of code in order to do things properly. +1

Comment: Can you also add an example?

Answer (score 17):

The solution that Piotr describes is actually not as complicated as it may sound. Here is an example where a `startupinfo` is passed to a `check_call` invocation to suppress the console window:

```
startupinfo = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
startupinfo.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW

subprocess.check_call(cmd, startupinfo=startupinfo)
```

Since the convenience functions `call`, `check_call`, and `check_output` forward their `**kwargs` to the `Popen` constructor, it is not required to use `Popen` directly.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare This question is specific to Windows, so it is no surprise that it could fail on other operating systems. If you want to help, you should state the exact error you get on Mac OS.

Comment: It's an elaborate work around (relative to how much code is otherwise necessary) so that one system (Windows) can behave the same as the others, but in the process breaks the others. I'm going with `shell=true` - it's short, it's sweet, and it works on all platforms. Oh, and the issue on Mac (and I assume *nix) is it throws an exception over `STARTUPINFO()` not being recognized.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare 1. It's not elaborate as it's only 3 simple additional lines in comparision to `shell=True` – `startupinfo = subprocess.STARTUPINFO(); startupinfo.dwFlags |= _subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW; startupinfo.wShowWindow = _subprocess.SW_HIDE)`. 2. It's Windows specific and as such should only be applied on Windows. Because of this, talking about *breaking other systems* does not make sense.

Answer (score 8):

People are a bit lazy... I would thx **@Piotr Dobrogost** and **@Frank S. Thomas** for their answers.

I came with this code who is runinng on Linux and Windows:

```
import platform
import subprocess
startupinfo = None
if platform.system() == 'Windows':
    import _subprocess  # @bug with python 2.7 ?
    startupinfo = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
    startupinfo.dwFlags |= _subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
    startupinfo.wShowWindow = _subprocess.SW_HIDE
```

Later...

```
args = [exe, ...]
out = subprocess.check_output(args, startupinfo=startupinfo)
```

Thx guys ;)

Additionally: just to note that the following code using 'call' also works on Python 2.7 (on Windows) with the 'startupinfo' code above:

```
def run_command(cmd, sin, sout):
    print "Running cmd : %s"%(" ".join(cmd) )
    return subprocess.call( cmd, stdin=sin, stdout=sout, startupinfo=startupinfo)
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me, thanks. I can't understand why anyone would want to use shell=True, it's just a bug waiting to happen.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that 'os.popen' doesn't produce console window. Script is running under 'pythonw'. Not sure about all cases but in my case it works well.

```
os.popen(command)
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what **@firsthand** said, I've read on the wxPython-user forums that you "replace" the current running application, that would be "command.com" or "CMD.exe", with pyw.exe or pythonw.exe when you use something like the following:

```
os.execl(sys.executable, *([sys.executable]+sys.argv))
```

see [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1750757/restarting-a-self-updating-python-script)

Although I do not know how you would pipe io in this case.

I believe one benefit of this approach is if you run your script multiple times your OS taskbar with not fill up with CMD icons. The other way if you have several CMD minimized in the taskbar and start closing them, it is impossible to tell which CMD goes with which pythonw script.