# Running a process in pythonw with Popen without a console

Tags: python, user-interface, console, popen, pythonw

I have a program with a GUI that runs an external program through a Popen call:

```
p = subprocess.Popen("<commands>" , stdout=subprocess.PIPE , stderr=subprocess.PIPE , cwd=os.getcwd())
p.communicate()
```

But a console pops up, regardless of what I do (I've also tried passing it NUL for the file handle). Is there any way to do that without getting the binary I call to free its console?

Comment: Are these commands that would normally be run in a console? Are you trying to run another GUI program that does not have a console?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

From [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/409002/):

```
import subprocess

def launchWithoutConsole(command, args):
    """Launches 'command' windowless and waits until finished"""
    startupinfo = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
    startupinfo.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
    return subprocess.Popen([command] + args, startupinfo=startupinfo).wait()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # test with "pythonw.exe"
    launchWithoutConsole("d:\\bin\\gzip.exe", ["-d", "myfile.gz"])
```

Note that sometimes suppressing the console makes subprocess calls fail with "Error 6: invalid handle". A quick fix is to redirect `stdin`, as explained here: [Python running as Windows Service: OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40108816/python-running-as-windows-service-oserror-winerror-6-the-handle-is-invalid)

Comment: Nice. Because it isn't obvious, let me point out that `startupinfo.wShowWindow = subprocess.SW_HIDE` is _implied_ (`SW_HIDE` (`0`) is the default value).

Answer (score 9):

just do `subprocess.Popen([command], shell=True)`

Comment: What `pyw` file? He needs to run an external application.

Comment: This works like a charm. You don't need a `.pyw` file.

Comment: Surprisingly, it is underrated this answer, since worked for me +1.

Answer (score 4):

According to [Python 2.7 documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) and [Python 3.7 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CREATE_NO_WINDOW), you can influence how `Popen` creates the process by setting `creationflags`. In particular, the `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` flag would be useful to you.

```
variable = subprocess.Popen(
   "CMD COMMAND", 
   stdout = subprocess.PIPE, creationflags = subprocess.CREATE_NO_WINDOW
)
```

Comment: Can you explain *why* this solves the problem? Thanks!

Comment: No such a flag in Python 2.7

Comment: this line
"from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, CREATE_NO_WINDOW"
will save you from all the prefix additions in the above example. (just in case you want your code a bit more compact.)

Comment: subprocess.CREATE_NO_WINDOW is elegant, but only available in Python >= 3.7.

Answer (score 1):

This works nicely in the win32api. The other solutions were not working for me.

```
import win32api
chrome = "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe\""
args = "https://stackoverflow.com"

win32api.WinExec(chrome + " " + args)
```

Answer (score 0):

#### The Python 'subprocess' Attribute shell=True

works on window 11

```
result = subprocess.run(['nslookup', '2.16.206.132'], shell=True, capture_output=True, text=True)
print(result.stdout)
```

The process is executed without open a shell-console.
This runs much more faster as like with ***shell=False*** ... :)

The result is here:

```
Server:  OpenWrt.lan
Address:  192.168.1.1

Name:    a2-16-206-132.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com
Address:  2.16.206.132
```

Answer (score -1):

You might be able to just do `subprocess.Popen([command], shell=False)`.

That's what I use anyways.  Saves you all the nonsense of setting flags and whatnot.
Once named as a .pyw or run with pythonw it shouldn't open a console.

Comment: shell=False is already the default, so I don't see what this is going to fix: https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen

Comment: `shell = False` will not change anything, the solution is to use `shell = True` with a `.pyw` file.