# Python 2.7 'subprocess.check_output' statement opens and closes a Windows command prompt

Tags: windows, python-2.7, subprocess

A 'For' loop in my Python 2.7.8 script contains:

```
ODate = subprocess.check_output(['exiftool', '-datedimeoriginal', image.jpg])
```

Under Windows 7, a Windows console window opens and quickly closes again each time this statement is executed. Not so when running on my Mac (OS X 9).

How can I prevent this?

P.S. ExifTool is a platform-independent Perl library plus a command-line application for reading, writing and editing meta information in a wide variety of files.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running a process in pythonw with Popen without a console](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1813872/running-a-process-in-pythonw-with-popen-without-a-console)

Comment: An alternative to hiding the window is to set the process [creation flags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684863%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` or `DETACHED_PROCESS`. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7006424/205580).

Comment: It's probably exiftool that is doing this. Far better to avoid calling exiftool.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do any of this, launching a separate process for each image to get its EXIF data.  Instead, just use Python directly:

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('image.jpg')
exif_data = img._getexif()
date = exif_data[36867] # DateTimeOriginal
```

From here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4765242/4323

Comment: Please mark it as a duplicate instead of copying the answer.

Comment: @simonzack: I hardly think this is a duplicate given how different the OP presented the problem.  It wasn't a question about EXIF at all really, until I made it one.  :)