# cmd/DOS window opens with GUI created with py2exe

Tags: python, user-interface, cmd, py2exe, pyqt5

I have created a GUI using PyQt5. The aim of the GUI is to pass some input data (images, shapefiles etc) and to use them in softwares (GIS mostly).

To launch the GIS I use the `subprocess.Popen` command line. I have used py2exe to create my app and my problem is that a DOS/cmd opens whenever I launch an operation.

My setup file looks like this :

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
setup(    
      windows=[{'script':'D:\App\projet.pyw',
                'options':{'py2exe':{'includes':['sip', 'PyQt5.QtGui', 'PyQt5.QtCore', 'PyQt5.QtWidgets', 'qwindows']}},
                'icon_resources':[(1, 'D:\App\images\logo.ico')]

            }]
      )
```

A cmd window stills open, eventhough I use `windows` instead of `console`. And I tried with both `.py` and `.pyw` .

So I'm not sure if this is py2exe related or if it's because I am launching softwares through my GUI, but I would like the cmd window not to open, just the GUI to be opened.

Comment: Does it happen if you launch the .exe directly? If not, it's a problem in your GUI launching it.

Comment: @ThiefMaster Yes it happens when I launch the .exe, when i'm using the GUI launched by the .exe

Comment: Can you please clarify: Is it the `subprocess.Popen` that causes the terminal window to open or does it happen even when the subprocess launching code is removed from your application?

Comment: @three_pineapples i dont know if it's the subprocess that causes the terminal window to open, i haven't tried to remove it (because i need it). I've read about STARTUPINFO, maybe it will fix the problem (what do you think ?)

Comment: I would suggest you do some basic debugging then to find out what is causing the terminal window to appear, and then update your question. It's pretty pointless speculating.

Comment: Resolved the problem !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer !

[Running a process in pythonw with Popen without a console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1813872/running-a-process-in-pythonw-with-popen-without-a-console?lq=1)

Source : http://code.activestate.com/recipes/409002/