# How to run an exe file in a completely hidden way

Tags: python-2.7

I'm able to execute an exe file via command prompt using below line:

```
process = subprocess.Popen("LogCollector.EXE ")
```

But the `LogCollector.EXE` *GUI* is still **visible**, Please suggest some method to run this completely in **hidden** way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running a process in pythonw with Popen without a console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1813872/running-a-process-in-pythonw-with-popen-without-a-console)

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
os.system('start /MIN notepad.exe');
```

Use this command in the window, it will run the application and minimize the application.
Maybe it will help you

Comment: How to pass argument here? Can you please provide the syntax and is it possible to run using subprocess?

Comment: Hi Malakar, Thanks for your valuable answer. It worked for me, and is there any way to completely hide the GUI? and how to pass the arguments to the EXE?

Comment: Still, I am not found any solution for completely hide the GUI,

Comment: Pass argument like os.system('start /MIN notepad "file.txt"');