# Python subprocess without a cmd window

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I am using `subprocess.Popen()` to execute python scripts inside other python scripts, but for some reason, a cmd window appears as a subprocess as well. I wanted to know how to remove it. I know there are multiple questions about this topic (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1813872/running-a-process-in-pythonw-with-popen-without-a-console)), but I was unable to make it work, mainly because the slot I'm using to stop that cmd window from appearing is the same one I'm using to call the python script (Also, I'm new to the subprocess library, so I don't know any workarounds or any alternative libraries I can use)

This is the line of code I'm using

```
subprocess.Popen("Example.pyw", shell=True)
```

Comment: Have you tried explicitly calling `Popen(["pythonw.exe", "<script path>"])`?  (You may need an absolute path to pythonw.exe if it isn't in your `PATH`).

Comment: I've tried this method and I haven't succeeded. I tried things like `subprocess.Popen("Example.pyw", "")` or `subprocess.Popen(["Example.pyw", ""])` (also using a path inside the second pair of quotation marks in both cases) and nothing worked

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, but I mean `Popen(["pythonw.exe", "Example.pyw"])` -- with `pythonw.exe` (not `python.exe`) as the first element of the args list.

Comment: Thx! Helped a lot