# os.subproccess how to avoid closing process after closing cmd

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, subprocess

I prepared .py script, which i run from command line. ('python test.py')
The last task of my script is to launch external application.
I use below function to launch independent process (.exe file)

```
subprocess.Popen(["C:/Program Files/Agisoft/PhotoScan Pro/photoscan.exe", (folder_z_nazwa+".psx")], shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

I would like to close cmd without terminating this subprocess. At this moment Agisoft is launched with cmd in background. When i click exit button on cmd window, agisoft is terminated immediately. I don't expect closing cmd automatically. I just want to avoid situation that user close cmd window accidentally and Agisoft will be closed too.

Comment: Possible a duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1813872/running-a-process-in-pythonw-with-popen-without-a-console or at least its answer could help you.

Comment: This answer didn't help me. Still the same problem.

Comment: Have you tried shell=True?

Comment: Yes, i've tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pythonw script_name.py
```

This will run your script in background,Even if you close cmd .