# Disable cmd opening from GUI (PyQt)

Tags: python, user-interface, cmd, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a GUI (created with PyQt5 and py2exe).
This GUI takes input data (shp, images..) and uses them as parameters in softwares (ie FME). Whenever I launch a task on a software through the GUi, a cmd opens.

To launch the softwares, I use `subprocess.Popen` in my script with a `shell=False` parameter.  Can that be the reason why the cmd opens ? Should I use `os.system` or something else to avoid having a cmd/DOS poping every time ?

Or is this not related to the way I launch anything ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1813872/running-a-process-in-pythonw-with-popen-without-a-console?lq=1 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390394/executing-subprocess-from-python-without-opening-windows-command-prompt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to have been solved in the [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1813872/running-a-process-in-pythonw-with-popen-without-a-console?lq=1) that I linked.  For reference, the solution appears to be as follows:

```
startupinfo = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
startupinfo.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
return subprocess.Popen([command] + args, startupinfo=startupinfo).wait()
```

Comment: OK thanks! I hadn't seen this before. I'll have a look and hopefully it will work

Comment: Checked it right now, works fine (even if i don't really understand it ;) ). Thanks!!!