# How to run CMD commands via subprocess.call() without opening CMD window?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, subprocess

I'm able to run commands through CMD with Python with `subprocess.call('insert command here')` but it opens the CMD window then closes right away. Is there a way to not open it at all?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/6390817/4004145

Comment: @OfirGottesman: That question is about `subprocess.check_call()` not `subprocess.call()`.

Comment: It has the same parameter as `subprocess.check_call()`, anyway I'll answer it for `subprocess.call`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `shell=True` when calling `subprocess.call`:

```
subprocess.call('insert command here', shell=True)
```

Comment: Do you happen to know why setting `shell=True` suppresses the `cmd` window? It seems to me like it would do the opposite of that…