# python calling external programs without opening console (dos prompt)

Tags: python, windows, subprocess

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Running a process in pythonw with Popen without a console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1813872/running-a-process-in-pythonw-with-popen-without-a-console)
>   [How do I eliminate Windows consoles from spawned processes in Python (2.7)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390762/how-do-i-eliminate-windows-consoles-from-spawned-processes-in-python-2-7)

I am using Python 2.7 and running the python scripts from within IDLE.

The commands I am executing are simple exe's that perform quick tasks.  The issue I am having is every time the external commands are called from within Python a *console* is created and it flashes on my screen and takes focus, thus preventing me from using my PC while executing various scripts.

Examples of how I am calling them from within Python are as follows:

```
result = call(["Commands\Set.exe", str(i), ARG2])
check_output(["Commands\Read.exe", ARG2])
```

Searching for a solution I came across adding the following

```
shell=True
```

to make the following command

```
check_output(["Commands\Read.exe", ARG2], shell=True)
```

However I still get the *console* appear every time an external command is called

Answer (score 4):

There might be two issues here.  First off, if your python scripts have the .pyw extension then they will be associated with pythonw which does not use a console*.  However, you have shell=True, which generates a console*.  You need to run the program and hide the console:

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen('hello.py',  creationflags=subprocess.SW_HIDE, shell=True)
proc.wait()
```

*Pedantically, it's not a dos prompt, it is a console window.  DOS - Disk Operating System - was an IBM mainframe OS. MS-DOS or PC-DOS command-line features were mirrored (with a lot of extra features) by cmd.exe (a Windows shell), which is a console program and so uses a console window.  It's that console window you need to hide.

Comment: ok I have tried adding the creationflags=subprocess.SW_HIDE, shell=True to the check_output line and I still get a *console* window appear ....

Comment: another comment ... I have updated my question to reflect the console usage ... I guess for completenesss  could say a "console window with dos prompt" because "C:\>" is actually a dos promopt compared to other consoles that give different prompts for instance >>>> in python ... now I guess that is being really pedantic ....

Comment: btw I am calling exe files not python scripts .... question updated.

Comment: I did say I was being pedantic ;-) Maybe the program is creating the console?

Comment: if I run the program from the console it does nothing other than return to the command prompt after a short while (a few seconds) for the set functions or with a response with the get functions so I do not think it is the program...

Comment: *However, you have shell=True, which generates a console* It generates a console but it's hidden one. See my comment [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1765078/1765093#comment17578243_1765093)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `startupinfo` parameter of `subprocess.Popen()` class' [constructor](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor).

```
startupinfo = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
startupinfo.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
startupinfo.wShowWindow = subprocess.SW_HIDE
subprocess.Popen(command, startupinfo=startupinfo)
```

You **do not need** `shell=True` if all you want is to hide console window; see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12964900/95735) answer.