# Running a commandline application from GUI silently

Tags: python, subprocess, py2exe

I would like to run the specific commandline application:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 audio.mp3
```

I'm running the command through a GUI, and when the console window doesn't exist, the `ffmpeg` process is running in a new cmd window.

Testers find the "black window that appears" scary and not userfriendly.

How can I run the application without any visible window coming up? `os.system()`, `subprocess.Popen()` and `subprocess.call()`  all do launch the cmd window.

If it matters, I'm using pyqt4 and py2exe. I'm targeting Windows OS users.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390762/how-do-i-eliminate-windows-consoles-from-spawned-processes-in-python-2-7

Comment: Thank you zigg. Can you please write it as a answer so i can choose it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This recipe at ActiveState may solve your problem:

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/409002/

Slight changes are required for Python 2.7.  See [How do I eliminate Windows consoles from spawned processes in Python (2.7)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390762/how-do-i-eliminate-windows-consoles-from-spawned-processes-in-python-2-7)

Answer (score 0):

Launch `ffmpeg` from the `START` command.  If you use the `/B` switch, no command window will be shown.

Answer (score 0):

Use `subprocess.Popen` (or `call`) and redirect stdout/stderr somewhere. They're currently hooked to your own process's stdout and stderr, which is why they're coming through.

If you need something that can integrate nicely with your GUI event loop, use Twisted's process-launching stuff.