# Can't Kill/Hide CMD console window

Tags: python, cmd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to avoid console window with .pyw file containing os.system call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1765078/how-to-avoid-console-window-with-pyw-file-containing-os-system-call)

Given a piece of Python code like this:

```
import os
os.system('set')
```

The CMD window pops up each time, despite me saving the file as a `.pyw`! Any help appreciated

Comment: I'm assuming Windows? Which version it doesn't for me on Windows 7.

Comment: Windows creates a command window whenever you run a command-line process. Can't be helped.

Answer (score 2):

It's *because* you're running Python from a window that you get a pop-up console window. Console programs can only be run from a console, and if the program environment doesn't already include one Windows will helpfully create it.

Answer (score 2):

os.system does open a command window by design.  The [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module should let you do somethings without opening a window.

Also, for certain commands (say copy, delete) you could use specialized OS commands that won't open a command window and have the advantage of being more cross-OS.