# Is it possible to disable cmd window when running a GDAL?

Tags: python

Is it possible to disable cmd window when running a GDAL?
Something like a "silent mode".

I use :

```
os.system('gdal_translate -of GTiff %s %s'%(in1, out1))
```

Comment: -of gtiff is not required as geotiff is the default. You only need to specify it if you want to write to a different output format.

Comment: This question is probably a better fit for StackOverflow as it's really a pure python question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this problem by switching to to the `subprocess` module, .e.g `subprocess.call`, and use the `shell = True` argument. I got this from StackOverflow, more specifically [from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1765078/how-to-avoid-console-window-with-pyw-file-containing-os-system-call).

Comment: shell = true is not required. Additionally, the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) docs warn the it can be a security risk if used with untrusted input.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [subprocess.Popen](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) class.

One advantage of using `Popen` instead of `call` is that it's easy to get the command output (with `call` you need to pass in a file-like object to get stdout/stderr so you'd need to use [StringIO](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html) if you need get them in string variables).

Here is an example:

```
def runcmd(cmd):
    ''' Run a command
        cmd = list of arguments or command string
        Returns  Returns (exit_code,stdout,stderr)
    '''
    import subprocess
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    stdout,stderr=proc.communicate()
    exit_code=proc.wait()
    return exit_code,stdout,stderr

exit_code,stdout,stderr=runcmd('gdal_translate -of GTiff %s %s'%(in1, out1))
# can also use a list, e.g.
# exit_code,stdout,stderr=runcmd(['gdal_translate', '-of', 'GTiff', in1, out1])

if exit_code: print 'Error ocurred:',stderr
else: print 'Success!',stdout
```

If you don't need the stdout/stderr text, you can use subprocess.call:

```
exit_code=subprocess.call(['gdal_translate', '-of', 'GTiff', in1, out1])
```