# Hide console when py-file only (no pyw) [ANKI add-on]

Tags: python, windows, command-line, console, anki

I am about to adjust the music fiddler add-on for ANKI SRS for windows users. 
Anki ONLY runs add-ons with with ending .py, not pyw. Is there any way to hide the console that automatically pops up when I run the code.

If not, is there a way no to unselect the console windows (i basically have to click on the main anki windows after every five seconds because the console that as already closed again was in selection).

The command I use so far for opening windows is for example:
    os.system('"nircmd.exe changesysvolume"'+ change)

The complete code is below
The console runs the nircmd.exe and the number of volume units the system sound should change.
Is there a possibility to adjust the code?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Music-Fiddler (a plugin for Anki)
# coded by D_Malik, malik6174@gmail.com
# Version 1
# License: GNU GPL, version 3 or later; http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html

"""
A simple plugin that fiddles with music volume to reinforce quick reviewing.

Before using:
- This plugin was made for Linux. It will require modification to work on another OS.
- Ensure that the "amixer" command works on your computer. If it doesn't, you're going to need     to modify the code somehow. Don't ask me how.//Amixer has been replaced by nircmd.exe for windows
- Change all lines (in the plugin source) marked with "CHANGEME" according to your preferences.
"""

    import os
from aqt import mw
from aqt.utils import showInfo
from os import system
from aqt.qt import *
from anki.hooks import addHook

    def resetMusicTimer():
    "Boosts volume back up and starts the music timer."
    #CHANGEME: The next lines are a python dictionary associating deck names with times (in         milliseconds) between volume-decrements.
    #Eg, when using the deck "brainscience", volume will decrement every 5 seconds. When using     a deck without a listed name, "other" is used.
    #Change this according to your decks. Decks with shorter, easier cards need less time.
    deckMusicTimes = {
                 "rocketsurgery"    :   3000,
                 "brainscience"     :   5000,
                     "other"            :   5000,
             }
    if mw.col.decks.current()['name'] in deckMusicTimes:
            mw.musicTimeToDecrement = deckMusicTimes[mw.col.decks.current()['name']]
    else:
        mw.musicTimeToDecrement = deckMusicTimes["other"]
    boostMusicVolume()
    mw.musicTimer = QTimer(mw)
    mw.musicTimer.setSingleShot(True)
    mw.musicTimer.start(mw.musicTimeToDecrement)
    mw.connect(mw.musicTimer, SIGNAL("timeout()"), decrementMusicVolume)
    #showInfo(mw.state)

def changeMusicVolume(change):
    "Changes volume according to string; can be either absolute ('40') or change ('2%-')."
    os.system('"nircmd.exe changesysvolume"'+ change) #CHANGEME somehow, if amixer doesn't work 

def boostMusicVolume():
    #showInfo("boosted") #To test changes, you can uncomment this line.
    os.system('"nircmd.exe changesysvolume 50000"') #CHANGEME somehow, if amixer doesn't work 
    #CHANGEME: Set to however high you want your volume to go each time it's boosted back.
    #Protip: your music-playing program might have its own "volume multiplier" that you can adjust easily.

def killMusicVolume():
    #showInfo("killed") #To test changes, you can uncomment this line.
    os.system('"nircmd.exe mutesysvolume 1"') #CHANGEME somehow, if amixer doesn't work 
    #CHANGEME: Set to how low volume should go when it dies, eg due to undoing a card.

def decrementMusicVolume():
    "When reviewing, decrements volume, then sets a timer to call itself. When not reviewing, kills volume and stops timer."
    if mw.state == "review":
        #showInfo("music volume goes down") #To test changes, you can uncomment this line.
        os.system('"nircmd.exe changesysvolume -5000"') #CHANGEME somehow, if amixer doesn't work 
        mw.musicTimer.start(mw.musicTimeToDecrement) #(start the timer again)
    else:
        killMusicVolume()
        mw.musicTimer = None #(kill the timer if you're not reviewing)

addHook("showQuestion", resetMusicTimer)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems using the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html)  module instead of `os.system` will solve your problem. Please see [How to avoid console window with .pyw file containing os.system call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1765078/how-to-avoid-console-window-with-pyw-file-containing-os-system-call) and [How do I hide the console when I use os.system() or subprocess.call()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7006238/how-do-i-hide-the-console-when-i-use-os-system-or-subprocess-call).