# How to restart a python script after it finishes

Tags: python, cron

I have a python script that will be running that basically collects data and inserts it into a database based on the last time the database was updated. Basically, i want this script to keep running and never stop, and to start up again after it finishes. What would be the best way to do this?

I considered using a cronjob and creating a lockfile and just have the script run every minute, but i feel like there may be a more effective way.

This script currently is written in python 2.7 on an ubuntu OS

Thanks for the help!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33334183/1340631 has a nice solution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could wrap your script in a

```
while True:
    ...
```

block, or with a bash script:

```
while true ; do
    yourpythonscript.py
done
```

Comment: In the past, when i have done things similar to this, the script runs but eventually encounters a recursion depth error. Would such an error occur if i did it this way?

Comment: No, because there is no recursion. This would occur if your script calls itself at the end.

Comment: Excellent, thank you for the help! This seems to be working and looping the script.

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
os.execv(sys.executable, [sys.executable] + sys.argv)
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Add it after you call your main function or at the end of your code! After trying many solutions on here this was the best for me.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your code in a while statement:

```
while 1==1: #this will always happen
    yourscripthere
```

Answer (score 0):

Ask it to run itself, with same arguments, should probably `chmod +x` it

```
os.execv(__file__, sys.argv)
```

Answer (score 0):

you could also prompt your user if they would like to run the program again in a wrap.

```
prompt = input("would you like to run the program?")  
while prompt == "yes":  
...  
...  
prompt = input("would you like to run program again?")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the --wait in your shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

while :
do
  sleep 5
  gnome-terminal --wait -- sh -c "python3 myscript.py 'myarg1'"
done
```

Answer (score -4):

```
while True:
    execfile("test.py")
```

This would keep executing test.py over and over.