# How to make a script automatically restart itself?

Tags: python

How do you make a python program automatically restart itself? So let's say there is a really simple program like:

```
var = input("Hi! I like cheese! Do you like cheese?").lower()
if var == "yes":
    print("That's awesome!")
```

Now, in a Python Shell, you would have to press either the <kbd>Run</kbd> button and then 'Run Module (F5)' or just the <kbd>F5</kbd> key on your keyboard. That is the first time you run it. When the program ended, you would go back to your `Cheese.py` file and then press <kbd>F5</kbd> to run the program again.

Everybody with me here?
OK, so my question is, how do you make the program restart itself automatically without you having to manually do it?

Comment: Do you mean you simply want to loop the program, or reload it, or... what? What's the actual problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: To put @jonrsharpe's comment in code: What about `while True: main()` ? Assuming `main()` is the function you're calling.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33334183/1340631 has a nice solution.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "restart itself."  If you just want to continuously execute the same code, you can wrap it in a function, then call it from within a `while True` loop, such as:

```
>>> def like_cheese():
...     var = input("Hi! I like cheese! Do you like cheese?").lower()  # Corrected the call to `.lower`.
...     if var == "yes":
...         print("That's awesome!")
...
>>> while True:
...     like_cheese()
...
Hi! I like cheese! Do you like cheese?yes
That's awesome!
Hi! I like cheese! Do you like cheese?yes
That's awesome!
```

If you want to **actually** restart the script you can execute the script again, replacing the current process with the new one by doing the following:

```
#! /bin/env python3
import os
import sys

def like_cheese():
    var = input("Hi! I like cheese! Do you like cheese?").lower()
    if var == "yes":
        print("That's awesome!")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    like_cheese()
    os.execv(__file__, sys.argv)  # Run a new iteration of the current script, providing any command line args from the current iteration.
```

This will continuously re-run the script, providing the command line arguments from the current version to the new version.  A more detailed discussion of this method can be found in the post "[Restarting a Python Script Within Itself](http://blog.petrzemek.net/2014/03/23/restarting-a-python-script-within-itself/)" by [Petr Zemek](http://blog.petrzemek.net/).

One item that [this article](http://blog.petrzemek.net/2014/03/23/restarting-a-python-script-within-itself/) notes is:

> If you use the solution above, please bear in mind that the `exec*()`
>   functions cause the current process to be replaced immediately,
>   [without flushing opened file objects](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/os.html#os.execv). Therefore, if you have any
>   opened files at the time of restarting the script, you should flush
>   them using `f.flush()` or [`os.fsync(fd)`](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/os.html#os.fsync) before calling an `exec*()`
>   function.

Comment: @shaikmoeed - Don't know for certain, not a use case I'm certain I'd want to execute. Probably insert a hash function in a loop to restart if the source file had changed. I would be more likely to execute that use case if I were watching for changes in a config file.

Answer (score 4):

or you can try

```
$ chmod a+x "name".py
```

Then, you can run the script via

```
$ ./daemon.py
```

In such a situation, to restart the script, use the following code:

```
os.execv(__file__, sys.argv)
```

Otherwise, when you run the script via

```
$ python daemon.py
```

use this code:

```
os.execv(sys.executable, ['python'] + sys.argv)
```

Either way, do not forget to import the `sys module`

Answer (score 3):

I use terminal on my Mac to re-start some of my python scripts with the function below.

```
import subprocess  
def run_again(cmd):
    subprocess.call(["bash", "-c", "source ~/.profile; " + cmd])
```

Note: Don't forget the space character after "profile;" or the function may fail silently!

Then at the bottom of my script to be re-started:

```
if some_condition:  
    run_again("python my_script.py %s" % my_new_arguments)
```

For the original question about the cheese script:

```
if var != 'yes':  
    run_again("python my_cheese_script.py")
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just use a shell script like test.sh and make sure in your linux terminal you `chmod +x test.sh`

As for the code:

```
#!/bin/bash

while :
do
  sleep 5
  gnome-terminal --wait -- sh -c "python3 myscript.py 'myarg1'"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap something in `while True:` to make it execute repeatedly, as `True` will always evaluate to `True`, like this:

```
while True:
    var = input("Hi! I like cheese! Do you like cheese?").lower() # <-- You had missed parentheses here        
    if var == "yes":
        print("That's awesome!")
```

There's another issue with your code though; you haven't called `lower` by putting parentheses after it.

Comment: How on earth would this make the program restart itself

Comment: @redFIVE It would run repeatedly without him having to press F5 again and again to test it with multiple inputs. That is how I interpreted the question.

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes, this answer addresses the *poorly* written question. Which can be answered with a google search anyway.

Comment: Maybe OP should use the proper nomenclature

Comment: @redFIVE Seeing his question, I highly down he knows the proper nomenclature.

Comment: I agree that the down votes for this answer are not deserved.

Comment: They have all been reversed except one

Answer (score 0):

I have written a blog post about this problem and I have provided its solution here in this [blog post](https://alistvt.medium.com/how-to-restart-a-python-program-from-inside-d3edecb98936).
Also I have created a [repository](https://github.com/alistvt/restarter) for this.

My solution works with `crontab` python package, I create a cronjob to run the program (let's say 1 minute later) after exiting the program.