# Python and Selenium - Reboot program and reuse same browser session

Tags: python, selenium, session

**Scenario**:

I am working an an auto whatsapp responder using whatsapp web.

I log in via **chromedriver** on selenium with **python 3**.

I run a function that does some stuff inside a `while True`.

**Problem**:

Sometimes, due to a lack of conectivity with the phone, or whatever other problems, the program just does not keep running the right way.

There are a lot of factors that might cause the whole thing to lose the right flow. I am analyzing them all and fixing them as best as I can.

**Question**:

I came up with the idea that maybe if I restart the whole thing every hour (or every whatever-thousands iterations) it would become more solid. As it will refind the flow no matter what happens, if I did not catch the bug yet.

Is it possible to restart the whole thing, without losing the browser session? Whatsapp web requires a QR scan, but it allows a "keep session alive in further connections" (which I do not really know how it works... if cookies or something else.)

**Note**: I know that a [python script can be rebooted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36018401/how-to-make-a-python-program-automatically-restart-itself), but the bigger problem here is to reuse the browser session. Of course I am doing my research. None of what I read so far made me come with a solid solution, and that is why I ask to all the super cool brains out there.

Comment: the "other problems" will likely cause errors to occur in your python script. You should be catching them and dealing with them.

Comment: @asongtoruin I am doing so. Still though, there are things that I did not catch yet or which are completely out of my control. And this would be a great add-on mode. Not to ignore everything and just reboot. But to fix as much as possible and also reboot for double trouble fixer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatsapp stores session in `localStorage` of the browser.

You can [extract the localStorage](http://scraping.pro/extract-browsers-local-storage-with-python/) and save to a file on closing of a session.

Upon instantiating a session check if this file exists, then parse the file and update localStorage with saved values before opening a URL.

Comment: I did so but still it won't grab the session. I posted new question because it now is a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45415178/python-and-selenium-reuse-a-whatsapp-web-session - Thank you.