# Python and Selenium - Reuse a whatsapp web session

Tags: python, selenium, session

I want to reuse a whatsapp web session via Python 3 and Selenium on Chromedriver.

For which I need to grab the localstorage of an existing session and set it to the new browser instance before opening whatsapp web again.

I do so, on a **logged in** session:

```
cacho="";
for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++){
cacho+="localStorage.setItem('"+localStorage.key(i)+"', '"+localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i))+"');"
}
alert(cacho)
```

With *driver.execute_script()*, and I get the working localstorage data.

I copy the whole thing (a few javascript lines) and then, when opening a new browser instance, I do:

```
driver.execute_script(the_whole_thing)
driver.get(url)
```

But the session is not alive.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you find any solution for that? I am trying to do the same thing.

Comment: @davis Nope, using imacros instead. It works like sunshine.

Comment: Use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31062789/how-to-load-default-profile-in-chrome-using-python-selenium-webdriver

Answer (score 0):

this is how you can reuse a whatsapp web session by storing cookies.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=chrome-data")
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe',options=chrome_options)
driver.get('https://web.whatsapp.com')
time.sleep(30)
```