# How automatically restart my code after first run (like Play Again)?

Tags: python, loops, playback, restart

Previous and related q: [How to make a script automatically restart itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36018401/how-to-make-a-script-automatically-restart-itself/69192132?noredirect=1#comment122293101_69192132)

Is also possible to set a specific word to let the code restart? Like at the end of my last print function add a kind of loop that allows the user to play again.

i.e. Do you want to play again? "Type "play again" to restart"

I am asking because it is useful to restart the process if the user made wrong or bad decisions.

edit:

```
#creating password generator

#Password Generator Project
import random
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
numbers = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
symbols = ['!', '#', '$', '%', '&', '(', ')', '*', '+']

print("Welcome to the PyPassword Generator!")
nr_letters = int(input("How many letters would you like in your password?\n")) 
nr_symbols = int(input(f"How many symbols would you like?\n"))
nr_numbers = int(input(f"How many numbers would you like?\n"))

#Eazy Level - Order not randomised:
#e.g. 4 letter, 2 symbol, 2 number = JduE&!91

#print(f'{nr_letters}+{nr_numbers}+{nr_symbols}')

password = ""
for char in range(1, nr_letters +1):
    password +=random.choice(letters)
for char in range(1, nr_numbers +1):
    password += random.choice(numbers)
for char in range(1, nr_symbols +1):
    password += random.choice(symbols)
print(password)

#Hard Level - Order of characters randomised:
#e.g. 4 letter, 2 symbol, 2 number = g^2jk8&P
passrandom = random.choice(password)
print(passrandom)
```

So in the end I would like to insert a function like Would y like to generate a new password?

Thanks

Comment: You enclose the whole code in a "while True:" loop from which you can "break" out if necessary. You can use "if" to test for a condition to break or not. Additionally "continue" can be helpful.

Comment: Wrap your code into a function. Ask the user the question at the end of the function, check the answer and call the function again to restart, or return from function to quit.

Comment: ok - wrapped functions - I'm gonna google it. thanks you, senpai :)

Comment: @albert Calling a function in itself is a bad idea if you don't understand what exactly happens then ("recursion", local variables, stack overflow).

Comment: @MichaelButscher it's just a simple code. nothing at the expert level. I would like to just reset the game, like the f5 button, or do not let the user refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

I supposed you can use threading to solve this problem but here you can give to conditions to restart your program. So I try to develop your concept in my way. Code is given below,

```
import threading

event_t=threading.Event()

def event():
    print("Event is waitting...")
    event_t.wait()
    print("Event is now working...")
    x=input('Are you play again?:')
    if x=="y":
        event()
    elif x=="n":
        return


t1 = threading.Thread(target=event)
t1.start()
```

Comment: Hi Dilshan! Interesting..Thanks for your reply! Just a question, I can do the same thing without that library? thank you!!!