# How do I set up a Raspberry Pi 3 B+ to Auto Deploy updates to a private Github Repo?

Tags: github, raspberry-pi3, webhooks

I bought a Pi 3 B+ and would like to have it auto clone/deploy new pushes (from a different machine) from a private github repo. I was just wondering how I would do that. I know I need a github web hook but I have no clue where to start. The Pi is going to be in a place I dont want to get to very often to update my code so this would make everything so much easier. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please follow our guidelines on [How to Ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your chances of getting a good response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. I just ended up creating a local Jenkins server and used a plugin to that would auto pull the repo from a webhook. to set up the webhook I made the local Jenkins server available to the internet so that the plugin would catch the webhook.

Answer (score 5):

1. You need to clone your repository to your Raspberry Pi

   `git clone git@github.com:your-username/your-repo-name.git`
2. Then before starting your script you just pull new version from github to your local repository and run updated script
   `git pull origin master`

example of starting script:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /your-local-repository-path/
git pull origin master
python your-script.py &
```

Dont forget make start script executable `sudo chmod 755 starting-script.sh`

Then you can run your starting script /.starting-script.sh

It shoud pull latest version of remote repository to your local repository before running.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks! I was more specifically looking on how I could make it so that as soon as I push an update on another machine it'll automatically pull it and restart with the revisions.

Comment: OK. Then I recommend to you these articles:  [How to check, if your repository is up-to-date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258243/check-if-pull-needed-in-git) and [How to restart script itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11329917/restart-python-script-from-within-itself). You can checking git in some interval in loop or etc. If my answer helped you, mark it as solution please. thank you.

Comment: Thank you so much for those articles! Do you know how to set up a webhook with github to communicate with my rPi?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this could help out someone else.

[Git-Auto-Deploy](https://github.com/olipo186/Git-Auto-Deploy) consists of a small HTTP server that listens for Webhook requests sent from GitHub, GitLab or Bitbucket servers. This application allows you to continuously and automatically deploy your projects each time you push new commits to your repository

Comment: This would be significantly easier than the original answer from 2018.