# How to restart the python in python 2.7?

Tags: python-2.7, restart

Here is the Code :

```
def restartSim():
        """Restarts the current program.
        Note: this function does not return. Any cleanup action (like
        saving data) must be done before calling this function."""
        python = sys.executable
        os.execl(python, python, * sys.argv)
```

This code will work perfectly fine in python 3.6 but in python 2.7.

How do i restart in python 2.7?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Restart python-script from within itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11329917/restart-python-script-from-within-itself)

Comment: @TimKlein Its not working in python 2.7... Can u post code please for python 2.7

Comment: What error are you seeing? What alternatives have you tried?

Comment: @TimKlein I am not getting any error...I tried def restart(self):
    self.shutdown()
    chdir(owd)
    # close some open fds
    for i in range(3,50):
        try:
            close(i)
        except :
            pass
 
    execl(executable, executable, *sys.argv)
    _exit(0)