# How do I restart a python app from within the app itself

Tags: python, django, subprocess, supervisord

Got a Django app that has users going through a setup wizard. After the wizard, the app needs to restart for it to pick the necessary settings.

The app is run on Ubuntu 18.04 and monitored using *supervisord*.

Ideally am looking to call *systemctl restart supervisord.service* from the Django app itself.

So I've tried

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run("systemctl restart supervisord.service")
```

However, this fails with the error:

> FileNotFoundError [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'systemctl
>   restart supervisord.service': 'systemctl restart supervisord.service'

There is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11329917/1082673) here on SO but that is an older question and the answers there are relying on **os.*** while as of this posting **subprocess** seems to be the preferred way or accessing OS function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Restart python-script from within itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11329917/restart-python-script-from-within-itself)

Comment: Its related but recent text seems to indicate that _subprocess.run_ is the _new_ preferred way?..

Answer (score 1):

Seen my error. The command should be run as:

```
subprocess.run(["systemctl", "restart", "supervisor.service"])
```

source: http://queirozf.com/entries/python-3-subprocess-examples

Answer (score 0):

For more cleaner way to start your own python program would be:-

```
import os
import sys
import psutil
import logging

def restart_program():
    """Restarts the current program, with file objects and descriptors
       cleanup
    """

    try:
        p = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
        for handler in p.get_open_files() + p.connections():
            os.close(handler.fd)
    except Exception, e:
        logging.error(e)

    python = sys.executable
    os.execl(python, python, *sys.argv)
```

Comment: Thanks. Will try it out. Would you mind explaining why its cleaner than using subprocess?