# How to restart script from another script without using a function in python?

Tags: python

I am trying to make a script that restarts the execution of another script using a function.  I have tried looking for a solution but haven't found anything that helps. Here's the code I have.

```
import sys, os, time
def crashHandle():
    sys.exit('An error occured.')
def haltAndRebootMain():
```

The function haltAndRebootMain is the one that restarts the main script.  I need help executing it.

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11329917/restart-python-script-from-within-itself

Comment: Lets have a basic explaination, to restart anything, we have to make everything to start from its default value, so you can have a function who is reseting/ making all values of variables to default and make a function call from where the execution had started for example you can have two functions: ```restart()``` and ```main()```