# Python: Restart script and exit it after function does not work

Tags: python, exit, restart, sys, os.system

After a run, the user is asked whether he wants to end the programme [with `sys.exit()`] or restart it [`os.system('main.py')`].

If he restarts the programme, the programme will run through until he can decide again whether to restart or exit.

If the user then wants to end the programme, however, this is not possible, the programme is restarted anyway.

Also `quit()` or `exit()` do not work.


This is the prompt that asks the user to restart or quit:

```
while (res := input("Do you want to play again [1] oder exit[2]?\n").lower()) not in {"1", "2"}:
    pass
if res == "1":
    os.system('main.py')
else:
    end_game = True  # Stops the loop, but is not necessary
    print("Sys.exit game")
    sys.exit(0)
```

When I use `subprocess.call(sys.executable + ' "' + os.path.realpath(__file__) + '"')`,

exiting the program works, but the program is not really restarted [variables set to 0 at the beginning are not at 0].


Small note, the reboot will restart another py file (main.py), which is the main file, with the following content:

```
class main:
    game_logic()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

game_logic() is the function from the other Py file in which the query for restarting and exiting is.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11329970/12580704) is interesting for you

Comment: @DecowVR This causes 'OSError Exec format error' to occur. After some research, I still don't know how to counteract this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to answer this question myself in the meantime.

I have done the following:

`game_logic()` is started via another py file (main.py).

At the restart which is executed within the `game_logic()` with `os.system('main.py')`, the current py file containing `game_logic()` is not terminated.

So if the main.py file is restarted, I have the file containing the `game_logic()` terminate afterwards.

It looks like this:

```
import os
import sys 

while (res := input("Do you want to play again [1] oder exit[2]?\n").lower()) not in {"1", "2"}:
    pass
if res == "1":
    os.system('main.py')
    exit()
else:
    exit()
```

Comment: You are right, but the problem of multiple processes persists. It is not desirable to create the process again in a recursive way. Better remap the image as I showed in my post. This way you'd reduce the space complexity from O(n) to O(1), 'n' being the number of consecutive restarts.

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
import sys 

while (res := input("Do you want to play again [1] oder exit[2]?\n").lower()) not in {"1", "2"}:
    pass
if res == "1":
    python = sys.executable
    os.execl(python, python, * sys.argv)
else:
    end_game = True  # Stops the loop, but is not necessary
    print("Sys.exit game")
    sys.exit(0)
```

and

```
class main:
    game_logic()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The example above should work for you. You should use `os.execl(...)` instead of `os.system(...)`. The last one creates new processes recursively and could cause an out of memory problem. You shouldn't create new processes, instead you want to replace the current process with a new one. This could be done with `execl()` or other calls from `exec` family.

To understand it properly, you may want to look [here](https://support.sas.com/documentation/onlinedoc/sasc/doc/lr2/execv.htm). It referes to C language, but it is kind of the same, because Python is wrapping around native calls.

> Like all of the exec functions, execv replaces the calling process
> image with a new process image. This has the effect of running a new
> progam with the process ID of the calling process. Note that a new
> process is not started; the new process image simply overlays the
> original process image. The execv function is most commonly used to
> overlay a process image that has been created by a call to the fork
> function.