# Start script from beginning after executed (python) Help please

Tags: python, loops, repeat

it's me again! xD
I was wondering around some forums trying to find an answer to yesterday's question...
And well i added the **LAST 4 LINES OF CODE** code to mine and i realised it kinda worked, the only thing i have to change now is the "break" property, i would like the code to start from the beginning once the user enters "y"
What can i enter for this to work?

```
import time
print("Booting System (Alfa V1.2, Bugs Fixed, Loop added)")
time.sleep(1)
print("Hello, and welcome to Training OS")
time.sleep(2)
print("What would you like to do ?")
time.sleep(1)
txt = raw_input("1.File Explorer  2.System Info.  ( 1 or 2 )")
if txt=="1": 
    print("Loading File Explorer") 
    time.sleep(1)
    print("  _____    _____ \n /     |  /     | \n |     |  |     | \n |_____|  |_____| \n  File1    File2  ")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    file = raw_input("1.File1 2.File2 ( 1 or 2 )")
    if file=="1":
        print("\n\nFile1:"
              "\n_______________________________________"
              "\nTOP SECRET UPDATE INFO:"
              "\n           Update Name . . . . 1.2"
              "\nEstimated Release Date . . . . 25.09.21"
              "\n(Official release date:. . . . 24.09.21)"
              "\n          New Features . . . . Loop"
              "\n_______________________________________")
    else:
        print("\n\nFile2:"
              "\n----------------------------------------"
              "\n                                        "
              "\n              Error 404.                "
              "\n             File Missing               "
              "\n                                        "
              "\n----------------------------------------")
else:
    print("\n\nSystem Info:"
          "\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
          "\n\nOs version: . . . . . 1.1 (New features: File Explorer)"
          "\n   Founded: . . . . . 22.09.2021, Baku, Azerbaijan"
          "\n  Products: . . . . . TOS"
          "\n\n***This OS is still being developed so some features are currently unaviable :(***"
          "\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")

while True:
    cmd = raw_input('\nAnything else? Enter \'y\'n')
    if cmd == 'y':
        break
import time
print("Booting System (Alfa V1.2, Bugs Fixed, Loop added)")
time.sleep(1)
print("Hello, and welcome to Training OS")
time.sleep(2)
print("What would you like to do ?")
time.sleep(1)
txt = raw_input("1.File Explorer  2.System Info.  ( 1 or 2 )")
if txt=="1": 
    print("Loading File Explorer") 
    time.sleep(1)
    print("  _____    _____ \n /     |  /     | \n |     |  |     | \n |_____|  |_____| \n  File1    File2  ")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    file = raw_input("1.File1 2.File2 ( 1 or 2 )")
    if file=="1":
        print("\n\nFile1:"
              "\n_______________________________________"
              "\nTOP SECRET UPDATE INFO:"
              "\n           Update Name . . . . 1.2"
              "\nEstimated Release Date . . . . 25.09.21"
              "\n(Official release date:. . . . 24.09.21)"
              "\n          New Features . . . . Loop"
              "\n_______________________________________")
    else:
        print("\n\nFile2:"
              "\n----------------------------------------"
              "\n                                        "
              "\n              Error 404.                "
              "\n             File Missing               "
              "\n                                        "
              "\n----------------------------------------")
else:
    print("\n\nSystem Info:"
          "\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
          "\n\nOs version: . . . . . 1.1 (New features: File Explorer)"
          "\n   Founded: . . . . . 22.09.2021, Baku, Azerbaijan"
          "\n  Products: . . . . . TOS"
          "\n\n***This OS is still being developed so some features are currently unaviable :(***"
          "\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
import time
print("Booting System (Alfa V1.2, Bugs Fixed, Loop added)")
time.sleep(1)
print("Hello, and welcome to Training OS")
time.sleep(2)
print("What would you like to do ?")
time.sleep(1)
txt = raw_input("1.File Explorer  2.System Info.  ( 1 or 2 )")
if txt=="1": 
    print("Loading File Explorer") 
    time.sleep(1)
    print("  _____    _____ \n /     |  /     | \n |     |  |     | \n |_____|  |_____| \n  File1    File2  ")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    file = raw_input("1.File1 2.File2 ( 1 or 2 )")
    if file=="1":
        print("\n\nFile1:"
              "\n_______________________________________"
              "\nTOP SECRET UPDATE INFO:"
              "\n           Update Name . . . . 1.2"
              "\nEstimated Release Date . . . . 25.09.21"
              "\n(Official release date:. . . . 24.09.21)"
              "\n          New Features . . . . Loop"
              "\n_______________________________________")
    else:
        print("\n\nFile2:"
              "\n----------------------------------------"
              "\n                                        "
              "\n              Error 404.                "
              "\n             File Missing               "
              "\n                                        "
              "\n----------------------------------------")
else:
    print("\n\nSystem Info:"
          "\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
          "\n\nOs version: . . . . . 1.1 (New features: File Explorer)"
          "\n   Founded: . . . . . 22.09.2021, Baku, Azerbaijan"
          "\n  Products: . . . . . TOS"
          "\n\n***This OS is still being developed so some features are currently unaviable :(***"
          "\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")

while True:
    cmd = raw_input('\nAnything else? Enter \'y\'n')
    if cmd == 'y':
        break
```

These four lines /\

Comment: Put it all in a while loop. At the end of the program add an if statement, if the user inputs “restart” continue the loop, if input != “restart” break the loop. I’m on my phone so I can’t formulate it better, good luck!

Comment: @Samuel Thanks a lot, i won't be able to do it by myself but thanks for explaining :)

Comment: Friendly notes: "it's me again! xD [...] yesterday's question [...] What can i enter for this to work?" 1) SO user list has [420k pages](https://stackoverflow.com/users?page=424183) and [python] has 50+/hour questions, so a chance somebody will remember and link the questions is quite a small one. Please use **links** between your questions if you want to show the relationship between them. Example: `[old question](https://...)` 2) Always duplicate the code and trim it to the smallest example you can produce for the behavior you need. It's simpler. 3) Show what you've tried and describe it. :)

Comment: @ThespAceCompany also, I was bored, so I created a sample for this problem to my private collection and submitted it as [an answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69319924/5994041). Feel free to study or utilize however you want.