# `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` is behaving strangely

Tags: python, multithreading, threadpool, python-multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

So, I am working on a project where I'm provided with some images and some excel sheets containing the information in context to those images. Now the images and excels are day to day data readings. They are orgaized in this folder structure:

[image: Dataset Organization]

Now the the task at hand:

- I need to go through those day to day image recordings, do semantic segmentation on the images, extract object height-width-area and then put them in their respective excel sheets. Like this picture below. The created output should be organized like this: [image: segmentation-results]

I have solved this part. But my main problem is, it takes almost around 26-32 minutes for image processing, segmentation and feature extraction for each day readings. So it takes around 1.5-2h in total. The data is growing simultaneously and we are taking three readings each week. So I wrote a multi-threading script that can start processing all the days simultaneously. This cut downs the total time taken in 26-32 minutes in total for all 3 days of data.

The script works most of the time but sometimes when I run the script it seems like `futures.append(executor.submit(processAndsegmentImages, day=day))` method is not starting threads for all 3 days. I checked and this happening. Sometimes it is only starting threads for 2 days or sometimes just one day.

Here's my code:

```
def processAndsegmentImages(day):
    # doing image processing, segmentation, and other analysis
    return '{} images processing and segmentation completed'.format(day)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start = time.time()
    rf = Roboflow(api_key="my_api_key")
    project = rf.workspace().project("my_project")
    model = project.version(1).model
    print('model loaded\n')
    import concurrent.futures
    days = ['day1', 'day2', 'day3']
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=min(32, os. cpu_count() + 4)) as executor:
        futures = []
        for day in days:
            print('adding {} to executor'.format(day))
            futures.append(executor.submit(processAndsegmentImages, day=day))
        for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
            print(future.result())
    end = time.time()
    tlapsed = end-start
    print('total time taken: {:.2f} minutes'.format(tlapsed/60))
```

The idea output should be like this:

```
loading Roboflow workspace...
loading Roboflow project...
model loaded

adding day1 to executor
adding day2 to executor
adding day3 to executor
created root directory: /home/arrafi/potato/segmentation_results/day2_segmentation_results
created root directory: /home/arrafi/potato/segmentation_results/day1_segmentation_results
created root directory: /home/arrafi/potato/segmentation_results/day3_segmentation_results
starting day1 images processing from /home/arrafi/potato/segmentation_results/day1_segmentation_results/day1_raw_images/
starting day3 images processing from /home/arrafi/potato/segmentation_results/day3_segmentation_results/day3_raw_images/
starting day2 images processing from /home/arrafi/potato/segmentation_results/day2_segmentation_results/day2_raw_images/

192 day1_images proccessed and saved at:  /home/arrafi/potato/segmentation_results/day1_segmentation_results/day1_images
created pred_images and json directory for day1 images

starting potato segmentation ... of 192 day1_images

192 day2_images proccessed and saved at:  /home/arrafi/potato/segmentation_results/day2_segmentation_results/day2_images
created pred_images and json directory for day2 images

starting potato segmentation ... of 192 day2_images

192 day3_images proccessed and saved at:  /home/arrafi/potato/segmentation_results/day3_segmentation_results/day3_images
created pred_images and json directory for day3 images

starting potato segmentation ... of 192 day3_images

................and some more outputs......................
```

Most of the time the script runs successfully but sometimes I notice that the script is only starting the process for one/two days. Like this below, it only started for day1 and day3:

```
loading Roboflow workspace...
loading Roboflow project...
model loaded

adding day1 to executor
adding day2 to executor
adding day3 to executor
created root directory: /home/arrafi/potato/segmentation_results/day1_segmentation_results
created root directory: /home/arrafi/potato/segmentation_results/day3_segmentation_results
starting day1 images processing from /home/arrafi/potato/segmentation_results/day1_segmentation_results/day1_raw_images/
starting day3 images processing from /home/arrafi/potato/segmentation_results/day3_segmentation_results/day3_raw_images/


192 day1_images proccessed and saved at:  /home/arrafi/potato/segmentation_results/day1_segmentation_results/day1_images
created pred_images and json directory for day1 images

starting potato segmentation ... of 192 day1_images

192 day3_images proccessed and saved at:  /home/arrafi/potato/segmentation_results/day3_segmentation_results/day3_images
created pred_images and json directory for day3 images

starting potato segmentation ... of 192 day3_images

................and some more outputs......................
```

[image: buggy output]

Can anyone point out why is this happening? Am I doing something wrong in calling the `ThreadPoolExecutor`? I have searched online for solutions but can't find out why is this happening because so far the code is not throwing any error. And the behavior is so random.

Comment: Is that LITERALLY your code, or are you actually pulling the `days` list from somewhere else?  Because that code could not possibly have produced that output.  It's not a question of the threadpool.  A `for` statement doesn't just arbitrarily skip one member.

Comment: yeah that is literally my script, sorry I might have been a little misleading there, I tried to copy-paste and edit the same output because of laziness but yes I put the print function in the for statement just to check that. It seems like the `futures.append()` is not working correctly. And I will fix that output, thanks for noticing

Comment: or my other theory is `executor.submit(processAndsegmentImages, day=day)` is not failing to start a thread sometimes but I can't find any reference to it failing anywhere except for some error in the script itself.

Comment: OK, now you changed your question.  Originally, the "adding day2" line did not appear in your output.  So, is that present, or is it absent?

Comment: no that always appears. It was my mistake while copy-pasting the output. I initially put that after the for loop to check if  some day is not appearing at all

Comment: okay I ran the script again and it's happening again, I will add a screenshot of the output too.

Comment: Does your code depend on things being run in order?  Because with threading, sometimes thread 2 is going to run before thread 1.  Is there some shared resource that might cause the second thread to abort?  You might consider adding a `try:` / `except:` / `print( sys.exc_info()[1])` / `traceback.print_exc()` in your thread so you can see the exceptions.

Comment: If you mean the order of days, no it doesn't. The data between days are independent. The script finishes running with only two/one days sometimes and I'm trying to figure out why. I've also added the last run screenshot

Comment: Hey, I also found out that after this happens I have to kill my Python-process from the system monitor but not from VScode or interrupt the script running. And then if I run the script again it works fine. Is it possible that the thread for day-2 might be running in the background from a previous run? Also I don;t have any while loop in my script

Comment: We don't see the code that prints "created root directory:". It could have errored or returned early or hung on some other operation or supressed the error. If it ended up returning `""`, your `print(future.result())` wouldn't have been very noticable.

Comment: Python waits for its threads to exit. Its a significant hint that this thread is waiting on some resource. Lots of prints in that code (especially as the first thing it does) would help. But as I mentioned, it could be a bug in this worker code.

Comment: hey @tdelaney, my script is rather long so I skipped putting everything in the question. Would it help if I posted the whole code there?

Comment: Also assuming, a thread is already running from a previous run, is there any way that I can clear the threadpool or any previously running threads while starting the scipt again? all I'm finding is resources on how to kill a thread while running the script itselt

Comment: Minimal examples are best! It may be hard for us to spot the problem with lots of code, especially if it is using some external service. I think the first step is lots of logging to narrow down the problem.

Comment: You could look at `threading._active` to see if there is anything called ThreadPoolExecutorX-X. You can call `executor.shutdown()` when a pool is done. Do `executor.shutdown(wait=True)` to make sure its done or `executor.shutdown(wait=True, cancel_futures=True)` to clear up (some) hung stuff.

Comment: okay, I will take a look into `threading._active`. @tdelaney here's my whole code if it helps you to understand better: https://github.com/arrafi-musabbir/shelf-life-analysis/blob/main/segmentation_script.py

Comment: Do you ever see "cannot create root directory:"? That rmdir / mkdir code can be tricky especially if something else has a file locked in that path. That's common on Windows. You llkely should print a bigger warning and `return` at that point. Otherwise you are using a partially deleted tree.

Comment: I don't know roboflow, but you use one of its models concurrently in multiple threads. it may not be reentrant. That sort of thing can cause hangs.

Comment: I'm not using Windows, I'm on POP OS. Yeah, you might be right with roboflow, I will check that out

Comment: Hey @tdelaney you were right, it was caused by Roboflow as it was keeping some threads busy well after the script finished running. So when I started a new run, all the processes were not starting. `threading._active` wasn't much help though. I fixed it by restarting the python program from within the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found out that sometimes if there's another python program running or a residual thread from a previous run is causing the issue. So, I added a small script at the start of my `multithreading` script, to restart the `python` program. Here's how I solved it:

```
import os
import sys
import psutil
import logging

def restart_program():
    """
    Restarts the current program, with file objects and descriptors cleanup
    """
    try:
        p = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
        for handler in p.get_open_files() + p.connections():
            os.close(handler.fd)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(e)

    python = sys.executable
    os.execl(python, python, *sys.argv)
```

The restart_program function is designed to restart the current Python program. It closes file objects and descriptors associated with the current process and then re-launches the program. This can be useful in certain scenarios, such as when you need to reload the program with new settings or configurations.
I got the script from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33334183/13520498