# Python: How do I make a restart() function?

Tags: python, restart

I'm wondering if I could make something similar to the quit command but instead of ending the script it restarts it from line 1.

Example:

```
def restart():
   #Something that would repeat the whole script.

answer = input("Test")
if answer = "Restart":
    restart()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Restarting a self-updating python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1750757/restarting-a-self-updating-python-script)

Comment: No sorry. I updated the question to clarify things.

Comment: Does my answer answer your question?

Comment: Not really since I already know I can just repeat it using while true but I want to make it into an actual function.

Comment: Now? I made it into a function.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I am probably being an absolute idiot right now but I think this works! I just had to import sys and os but yes it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said, one way to do this is to make an infinite loop, using `while True:` or something else.

But if you want to make it into a function you have to do this:

```
import os
import sys

def restart():
    os.execl(sys.executable, sys.executable, *sys.argv)
```

For example:

```
import time
import os
import sys

def restart():
    os.execl(sys.executable, sys.executable, *sys.argv)

print("Test")
time.sleep(1)
restart()
```

Answer (score 0):

The typical way to do this would be to write a function, and run it forever in a loop.

Comment: I did this but I just want to make a restart since I will be doing this alot.